# Grease pencil to Mesh with Custom brush textures

Tags: mesh, texturing, grease-pencil

I recently got really into this cool 3D watercolor style by Gaku. I watched his tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6oGbFIRqt7A&t=407s) and for the leaves and cloudy textures he uses a grease pencil from a bush pack. I was wondering if there is a way to convert that grease pencil to a mesh with the custom brush textures still there.

All I can find online is info on how to convert grease pencil strokes to curves but nothing about a way to keep the texture of the brush. I thought it cant be done but then i saw one of Gaku's twitter video (screenshots below) and when he toggles to solid and wireframe you can see the textures from the same brushes have geometry and he has converted them somehow. Link to video (https://twitter.com/Gakutadar/status/1603921578932441088?s=20)

I want to try and convert it so i can bake the textures and export as an fbx. Would really appreciate any help :)

[image: https://twitter.com/Gakutadar/status/1603921578932441088?s=20]

[image: https://twitter.com/Gakutadar/status/1603921578932441088?s=20]